# copy.deepcopy() of a _wmi_object results in Exception

Tags: python, copy, wmi

I am using WMI 1.4.9 in Python, to access WMI.

I would like to do a deepcopy of a _wmi_object that is returned as part of WQL that I perform using the wmi module in python.

My code is as shown below,

```
aproc = wmi.WMI(moniker=self._wmi_namespace).query("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'svchost.exe'")[0]
copiedproc = copy.deepcopy(aproc)
```

But i get this exception, when `deepcopy(..)` is performed.

```
object.__new__(PyIDispatch) is not safe, use PyIDispatch.__new__()
```

I do not want to maintain the reference, instead I want the object to be deep copied, before I store them and make use of them.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

PyIDispatch cannot be copied. Objects that are derivative of IDispatch can be only created new.

If using python WMI module, you could only create a new WMI object and copy the properties of older object one by one into the newer one.

For exaemple, creating a new Win32_Process instance,

```
newproc = wmi.WMI().Win32_Process.new()
```

Then update each property of this instance with older instance's property.